# Use of this "die()" in visitor counter script

Tags: php

I downloaded a PHP script to count total number of 'visitors' and 'unique visitors' from

http://code.google.com/p/simphp/downloads/detail?name=simphp.php (with its documentation [here](http://code.google.com/p/simphp/wiki/README))

I understood whole script except the use of die() function here :

```
if (parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY)=="code") {
//Show include() info.
die("&#60;? include(\"" . __FILE__ . "\"); ?&#62;");
```

I read php die manual from official websites, but all i found was "Print a message and exit the current script".
(this code works only when i upload it to my godaddy or 000webhost account and doesn't works for localhost on IIS).
I know this question might have been already answered but i don't know the correct phrase for it.

What does the `die()` statement do, and why is it there?

Comment: Are you asking what `die()` does? Or are you asking why the script does not work on your localhost?

Comment: `&#60;` is `<`.  `&#62;` is `>`.  The `die` should echo `<? include("file.php"); ?>` to the screen, then exit the script.

Comment: You're not going to be able to output PHP code; by the time the output is generated, PHP is done parsing that script and won't reparse it.

Comment: I am asking whats the use of die() function here....

Comment: the `die()` function exits the current script and stops processing any remainder of the script after printing whatever is included in the brackets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code just displays `include` statement (only displays, like you can read from comment above it).

It can be also written as

```
echo "&#60;? include(\"" . __FILE__ . "\"); ?&#62;";
die;
```

I think it's easier to understand in that form.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it's builtin help. If you want to know what exact PHP code you have to paste in your site pages, you load the script appeding `?code` to the URL and you get the code.

It looks like the documentation has a typo:

> Replace "path/to/simphp.php" with the relative or absolute path to the
>   simphp.php from the webpage. If you don't know the absolute path to
>   the simphp.php file, visit the file directly in your browser, placing
>   `"?display=true"` at the end (minus quotes). For example:
>
> ```
> http://example.com/simphp.php?display=true
> ```

The actual parameter is called `code` rather than `display` and cannot have neither a value nor other parameters.

Comment: In fact, the way the request is checked, it *can't have* a value.  If the query part isn't literally just like `?code`, the `if` won't catch it.

Comment: @cHao - Exactly, I'll clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

It is used to stop execution of the sript. This technique is often used if there is some error in code and it can't/shouldn't execute further. In this situaion it means that if

```
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY)
```

equals to "code" script cannot execute further and should be stopped right now.